# SQLite implementation in swift 5?

Tags: swift, sqlite, swift5

> **Create PersonModel class to store data in localObject**

```
import Foundation

class PersonModel {
    
    var name : String = ""
    var age : Int = 0
    var id : Int = 0
```

> //initialiser method to bind the data

```
init(name : String , age : Int ,id:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

> Create DBHelper class to make connection to database and other
> functionality

```
import SQLite3

class DBHelper
{
    init()
    {
        db = openDatabase()
        createTable()
    }

    let dbPath: String = "myDb.sqlite"
    var db:OpaquePointer?
```

> //function to open database

```
    func openDatabase() -> OpaquePointer?
    {
        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent(dbPath)
        var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK
        {
            print("error opening database")
            return nil
        }
        else
        {
            print("Successfully opened connection to database at \(dbPath)")
            return db
        }
    }
```

> Function to create tables

```
    function createTable() {
        let createTableString = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,name TEXT ,age INTEGER);"
        var createTableStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, createTableString, -1, &createTableStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK
        {
            if sqlite3_step(createTableStatement) == SQLITE_DONE
            {
                print("person table created.")
            } else {
                print("person table could not be created.")
            }
        } else {
            print("CREATE TABLE statement could not be prepared.")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(createTableStatement)
    }
    
    
    func insert(id:Int, name:String, age:Int)
    {
        let persons = read()
        for p in persons
        {
            if p.id == id
            {
                return
            }
        }
        let insertStatementString = "INSERT INTO person (Id, name, age) VALUES (?, ?, ?);"
        var insertStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatementString, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            sqlite3_bind_int(insertStatement, 1, Int32(id))
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 2, (name as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
            sqlite3_bind_int(insertStatement, 3, Int32(age))
            
            if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
                print("Successfully inserted row.")
            } else {
                print("Could not insert row.")
            }
        } else {
            print("INSERT statement could not be prepared.")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
    }
```

> Function to fetch data

```
    func read() -> [PersonModel] {
        let queryStatementString = "SELECT * FROM person;"
        var queryStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        var psns : [PersonModel] = []
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryStatementString, -1, &queryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            while sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW {
                let id = sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 0)
                let name = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 1)))
                let year = sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 2)
                psns.append(PersonModel(name: name, age: Int(year), id: Int(id)))
                print("Query Result:")
                print("\(id) | \(name) | \(year)")
            }
        } else {
            print("SELECT statement could not be prepared")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement)
        return psns
    }
    
    func deleteByID(id:Int) {
        let deleteStatementStirng = "DELETE FROM person WHERE Id = ?;"
        var deleteStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteStatementStirng, -1, &deleteStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStatement, 1, Int32(id))
            if sqlite3_step(deleteStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
                print("Successfully deleted row.")
            } else {
                print("Could not delete row.")
            }
        } else {
            print("DELETE statement could not be prepared")
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(deleteStatement)
    }
    
}
```

> Create controller class to represent data on UIGraphics

```
import UIKit

class HomeController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var personTableView: UITableView!
    var persons:[PersonModel] = []
    var db:DBHelper = DBHelper()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
```

//insert data to database

```
        db.insert(id: 1, name: "Bilal", age: 24)
        db.insert(id: 2, name: "Bosh", age: 25)
        db.insert(id: 3, name: "Thor", age: 23)
        db.insert(id: 4, name: "Edward", age: 44)
        db.insert(id: 5, name: "Ronaldo", age: 34)
                
        persons = db.read()
        
        personTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
}

extension HomeController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    function tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
        {
            return persons.count
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
            let identifier = "PersonCell"
            var cell: PersonCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? PersonCell
            if cell == nil {
                tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PersonCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? PersonCell
            }
            
            cell.idLabel.text = "\(persons[indexPath.row].id)"
            cell.ageLabel.text = "\(persons[indexPath.row].age)"
            cell.nameLabel.text = "\(persons[indexPath.row].name)"
            
            return cell
        }
    
    function tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat 
    {
        return 100
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you skip the question? What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Is there a question or are asking for a code review? If the latter, this belongs in https://codereview.stackexchange.com. There are minor observations that I might make, but unless there is a problem, this is the wrong forum for this question.